# How to use bgl?

Tags: python, scripting, opengl

I want to render simple lines on the 3D viewport through a modal operator but not using glBegin/End because those commands are deprecated in opengl 3.3 and will not be avaliable on 2.8 leaving me without options since I am noob on open GL.

Could someone giveme a help at least on finding good examples on the openGl?
I didn't find anything that actually work on the most recent versions.

Seems like if I want to render simple stuff, now I will need to know about buffers, arrays, bytes, shaders and all that scarry stuff.

Comment: Impatient to find more info on this myself... so I'm keeping an eye on the [math_vis addon](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/browse/master/space_view3d_math_vis/;d8e19001f08387edfe8e14c551166f1d43627426)

Comment: Also, interested in doing this. It's a bit frustrating right now. Nobody seems to know anything specific about the future of bgl in 2.8